# Formatting aand setting up Raid on a secondary and tertiary drive

Tags: server, raid

I am a Ubuntu Server newbie and an amateur, more like a newbie, with Ubuntu Desktop. So FYI... Sorry for any potential redundancy, but most of the formation I have found is to setup RAID on a fresh install.

I set up Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS on a 500 GB drive. I plan to utilize this drive for the to boot the Ubuntu file system, programs etc. I also have two 2 TB WD Red drives that I would like to use for the data. I have found [this](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/09/10/add-a-second-drive-to-your-ubuntu-server/) in order to mount and format a new drive. Although it is for 9.04 is it still relevant? Is EXT 4 a good idea if the client accessing the server is Windows?

If the core of the tutorial is still relevant, once that is done I need some guidance on setting up the two drive in a RAID 1 format.

Ultimately the server is going to be a simple file server with MySQL in order to run a database for a CAD program in Windows.

I am open to any tutorials or guidance that can be provided, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up RAID1 device is quite simple:

- create partitions for RAID on 2TB HDDs
- assemble md0 device
- mount assembled /dev/md0 device

You can find step-by-step instructions here: 
[How can I add a RAID 1 array in Ubuntu 10.04?](https://superuser.com/questions/230497/how-can-i-add-a-raid-1-array-in-ubuntu-10-04).

Comment: Thoughts on EXT 3 or 4 with use with a windows client?

Comment: [Ext4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4) is the successor for Ext3. So, If you have no good reason for using Ext3 - always use Ext4.

Comment: I followed the tutorial verbatim and everything seems to work, when   reboot it will not mount the files folder and need to skip it to proceed.

Comment: Boot the system. Check RAID status `cat /proc/mdstat`. Try to `mount /dev/md0`. Check /etc/mdadm.conf

Comment: nab. Thank you so much. It mounted on boot. Even though I specified md0 during the process, the drive was actually assigned md127.